# how to display ion-content above the ion-footer

Tags: css, angular, sass, footer, ionic2

My ion-footer display above the ion-content Please take a look at this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCazE.png).(when i have more item my view appears like this)

i need my actual view like this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LRkfm.png) .(this is the look i need)

i tried adding ion-navbar inside my ion-footer but still same result.

here is my code:

```
<ion-footer *ngIf="shopingCart.length > 0">
  <ion-toolbar color="favorite">
    <ion-row class="footer_color" >
      <ion-col width-50>
        Total: {{total}}
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col width-50 (click)="checkoutNav();">
       Checkout  >
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: Are you placing the `ion-footer` outside the `ion-content` element?

Comment: Yes i am doing like that

Comment: for time being i have done like giving `<div padding></div>` at the end of my ion-content to have empty spacing

Comment: Can you please add the code of the rectangle that has the sub-total and free shipping? It may be related to that part of the code...

Comment: i think i have sent you two images the ion-card details are `<ion-card *ngIf="shopingCart.length > 0">
    <div *ngFor="let cost of allTotal">
      <ion-row>
        <ion-col width-80>
          {{cost.title}}
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col width-20>
          {{cost.value}}
        </ion-col>
      </ion-row>
    </div>
  </ion-card>` this the ion-card i have in my code